# OpenMP - Starting a new thread in each loop iteration

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm having trouble adjusting my thinking to suit OpenMP's way of doing things.

Roughly, what I want is:

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   doStuff();
   thread t;
   t.start(callback(i)); //each time around the loop create a thread to execute callback
}
```

I think I know how this would be done in c++11, but I need to be able to accomplish something similar with OpenMP.

Comment: What about boost-thread or QT threads? OpenMP is good for numerical calculations, as the threads have a lot overhead compared with normal threading frameworks. If you want threading you will have better success in using a threading framework.

Comment: OpenMP doesn’t work that way. You want explicit thread control, OpenMP (especially the `parallel for` construct) is all about *hiding* explicit thread control from you.

Comment: The sample you gave above can not be done exactly this way due to data dependency, I think. The sample is to short to judge this. You need to change the way you tackle your problem to make it suitable for OpenMP. See below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want are OpenMP tasks, available in OpenMP v3.0 and later compliant compilers. It goes like:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        doStuff();
        #pragma omp task
        callback(i);
    }
}
```

This code will make the loop execute in one thread only and it will create 50 OpenMP tasks that will call `callback()` with different parameters. Then it will wait for all tasks to finish before exiting the parallel region. Tasks will be picked (possibly at random) by idle threads to be executed. OpenMP imposes an implicit barrier at the end of each parallel region since its fork-join execution model mandates that only the main thread runs outside of parallel regions.

Here is a sample program (`ompt.cpp`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

void callback (int i)
{
   printf("[%02d] Task stated with thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
   sleep(1);
   printf("[%02d] Task finished\n", i);
}

int main (void)
{
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp single
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         #pragma omp task
         callback(i);
         printf("Task %d created\n", i);
      }
   }
   printf("Parallel region ended\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -o ompt.x ompt.cpp
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./ompt.x
Task 0 created
Task 1 created
Task 2 created
[01] Task stated with thread 3
[02] Task stated with thread 2
Task 3 created
Task 4 created
Task 5 created
Task 6 created
Task 7 created
[00] Task stated with thread 1
Task 8 created
Task 9 created
[03] Task stated with thread 0
[01] Task finished
[02] Task finished
[05] Task stated with thread 2
[04] Task stated with thread 3
[00] Task finished
[06] Task stated with thread 1
[03] Task finished
[07] Task stated with thread 0
[05] Task finished
[08] Task stated with thread 2
[04] Task finished
[09] Task stated with thread 3
[06] Task finished
[07] Task finished
[08] Task finished
[09] Task finished
Parallel region ended
```

Note that tasks are not executed in the same order they were created in.

GCC does not support OpenMP 3.0 in versions older than 4.4. Unrecognised OpenMP directives are silently ignored and the resulting executable will that code section in serial:

```
$ g++-4.3 -fopenmp -o ompt.x ompt.cpp
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./ompt.x
[00] Task stated with thread 3
[00] Task finished
Task 0 created
[01] Task stated with thread 3
[01] Task finished
Task 1 created
[02] Task stated with thread 3
[02] Task finished
Task 2 created
[03] Task stated with thread 3
[03] Task finished
Task 3 created
[04] Task stated with thread 3
[04] Task finished
Task 4 created
[05] Task stated with thread 3
[05] Task finished
Task 5 created
[06] Task stated with thread 3
[06] Task finished
Task 6 created
[07] Task stated with thread 3
[07] Task finished
Task 7 created
[08] Task stated with thread 3
[08] Task finished
Task 8 created
[09] Task stated with thread 3
[09] Task finished
Task 9 created
Parallel region ended
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks right but doesn't seem to run as I expected. It doesn't seem to immediately return control back to the loop. For example, after the first loop iteration, I would expect control to return to the statement following callback(i), in this case the i++ statement of the for loop.

Comment: Did you compile with OpenMP support enabled? What compiler (+ version) are you using? It works for me with GCC 4.4.5 and ICC 12.1.3 on Scientific Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I had omitted the -fopenmp flag while debugging and forgot to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

For example have a look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP.

`#pragma omp for`

is your friend. OpenMP does not need you to think about threading. You just declare(!) what you want to be run in parallel and the OpenMP compatible compiler performs the needed transformations in your code during compile time.

The specifications of OpenMP are also very enligthing. They explain quite well what can be done and how: http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/

Your sample could look like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   doStuff();
   thread t;
   t.start(callback(i)); //each time around the loop create a thread to execute callback
}
```

Everything in the for loop is run in parallel. You have to pay attention to data dependency. The 'doStuff()' function is run sequentielly in your pseudo code, but would be run in parallel in my sample. You also need to specifiy which variables are thread private and something like that which would also go into the #pragma statement.

Comment: Now you’re mixing OpenMP with explicit threading, not what the OP wants.

Comment: I understood he had a general issue by understanding OpenMP.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, thanks for responding though.